# HTML Comment Box Email Notification

Tags: php, html

Good Evening,

I have a free HTML comment box code that I use on a website for visitors to post comments. Since I do not have this in a widget or on a specific blog page or post I do not get notifications when someone leaves a comment. I have been racking my brain as to what code and how the code should look so that when they post I get an email telling me that they have so i can do and reply if necessary. This is the code I used for my free html comment box:

```html
<!-- Begin Comments JavaScript Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" async>
    function ajaxpath_5c69eeb9d5ae6(url){
        return window.location.href == '' ? url : url.replace('&s=','&s=' + escape(window.location.href));
    }
    (function(){
        document.write('<div id="fcs_div_5c69eeb9d5ae6"><a title="free comment script" href="http://www.freecommentscript.com">&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Free HTML User Comments</b>...</a></div>');
        fcs_5c69eeb9d5ae6=document.createElement('script');
        fcs_5c69eeb9d5ae6.type="text/javascript";
        fcs_5c69eeb9d5ae6.src=ajaxpath_5c69eeb9d5ae6((document.location.protocol=="https:"?"https:":"http:")+"//www.freecommentscript.com/GetComments2.php?p=5c69eeb9d5ae6&s=#!5c69eeb9d5ae6");
        setTimeout("document.getElementById('fcs_div_5c69eeb9d5ae6').appendChild(fcs_5c69eeb9d5ae6)",1);
    })();
</script>
<noscript><div><a href="http://www.freecommentscript.com" title="free html user comment box">Free Comment Script</a></div></noscript>
<!-- End Comments JavaScript Code -->
```

Thank you so much for your help. I truly appreciate it.

Comment: Hello. Based on the information you have provided, I think you would need to consult the documentation for this free comment box to see if there is an e-mail function of some kind. If you can post the link here, we may be able to help you.

Comment: From what I read on https://www.freecommentscript.com/ it should be doing that already. If you are confident that you entered the correct email address and you have already checked your spam folder I would recommend contacting the code provider. Here's their support page: https://www.freecommentscript.com/Support.php

Comment: Voting to close since this problem can't be reproduced here. This is an issue that needs to be resolved by the code provider

Comment: Thank you all so much! I thought it should but wasnt sure since I didnt get an email when a person commented. Thank you again!

Comment: Could you confirm for me if the posted comments are registered under the Wordpress Comments dashboard? If so, I might have a solution for you,